Track the exit status of python script using subprocess
Hey I am a beginner in development and I need your inputs please.
I have an ops.py which monitors the exit status of main.py:
Below is the ops.py:
import subprocess
import sys

def main():
    try:
        process = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'main.py'])
        process.wait()
        exit_status = process.returncode
        print("Exit status of the main script:", exit_status)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

If I run the ops.py independently I get the output, but I need to execute this script only when the main.py is executed, inorder to track the exit status of main.py only when it is being executed.
I tried importing the ops.py in main.py, (doesn't work) I used subprocess.run(['python', 'ops.py']) (doesn't work)
I am doing this experiment to know if the main.py failed of passes during execution.
Open to Suggestions

I'm having trouble understanding why you have a problem here in the first place. If you want all executions of main.py to go through this wrapper, then fix whatever's directly invoking main.py to invoke your wrapper instead. If need be you can even enforce this with file permissions, using a setgid executable that runs the program through your wrapper and ensuring that only the group that the wrapper is setgid to has access to read the source to main.py.

In general, you don't get to see the exit status of processes that aren't your children; there's nowhere you can hook into the OS to see the exit status of every program anything anywhere on the system runs, unless you use debugging tools like ebpftrace or sysdig, and that's massive overkill. Just install your tool as a wrapper and you're done.

I don't understand the problem. If you want to know whether main.py failed, you can just check that in whatever system is executing main.py, no? Like if you have a shell script, if python main.py; ....

let me put this simple, I  have minimal permission to the main script, i.e at max I can use a import statement and / or call a function once, after that I don't even get to see the main_script.  To know if the script ran successful or not is what am working on, that's why I went with the idea of ops.py. I know its a crazy idea, but hey that's the crazy  requirement am breaking my head. Am ableto run the ops.py if I directly call the function in the opy.py. But it doesn't stop until interrupted. well yeah that makes sense,

What program, other than your ops.py, runs main_script? If it's something like a systemd service, then systemd can be told how to handle various exit modes.
